# implementation of dirty_expire_centisecs

Tags: linux-kernel

I'm trying to understand the behavior of dirty_expire_centisecs parameter on servers with 2.6 and 3.0 kernels.

Kernel documentation says (vm.txt/dirty_expire_centisecs)
"Data which has been dirty in-memory for longer than this interval will be written out next time a flusher thread wakes up."

which implies, dirty data that has been in memory for shorter than this interval will not be written.

According to my testing, behavior of dirty_expire_centisecs is as follows: when writeback timer fires before the expire timer, then no pages will be flushed, else all pages will be flushed. 
If background_bytes limit reaches, it flushes all or portion depending on the rate, independent of both timers.

My testing tells me at low write rates (less than 1MB per sec), dirty_background_bytes trigger will flush all dirty pages and at slightly higher data rates (higher than 2MB per sec), it flushes only a portion of the dirty data, independent of expiry value.

This is different from what is said in the vm.txt. It make sense not to flush the most recent data. To me, observed behavior is not logical and practically useless. What do you guys think ?

My test setup:
Server with 16GB of RAM running Suse 11 SP1, SP2 and RedHat 6.2 (multi boot setup)

```
vm.dirty_bytes = 50000000            // 50MB <br>
vm.dirty_background_bytes = 30000000 // 30MB <br>
vm.dirty_writeback_centisecs = 1000  // 10 seconds <br>
vm.dirty_expire_centisecs = 1500     // 15 seconds <br>
```

with a file writing tool where I can control the write()'s per sec rate and size.

Comment: Has anyone got any comments. At least confirming or rejecting my observations ?

Comment: I've observed the same behavior for dirty_expire_centisecs, on Ubuntu kernel 3.5.0-23-generic. I agree with you, it seems quite useless. I haven't experimented with dirty_background_bytes. Usually I set dirty_background_ratio to 50% but it's irrelevant because the dirty_expire timer always trips before it gets there.

Comment: I am observing a behavior when dirty pages get flushed before reaching dirty_background_bytes and dirty_bytes values. Could anyone enplane why this can happen, had anyone else observed this kind of behavior ?

Comment: I've seen this on ext3 and ext4, due to their commit=xx mount option. Basically ext3/ext4 have per-filesystem flush timer, which is completely independent of /proc/sys/vm settings. I've found no way to disable this and make it honor the system settings.

Answer (score 13):

I asked this question on the linux-kernel mailing list and got an answer from Jan Kara. The timestamp that expiration is based on is the modtime of the inode of the file. Thus, multiple pages dirtied in the same file will all be written when the expiration time occurs because they're all associated with the same inode.

http://lkml.indiana.edu/hypermail/linux/kernel/1309.1/01585.html

Comment: Thanks hyc. This explains perfectly why it behaves the way it behaves.